# GML Filename gives layer name of "PREDEFINED" when imported as vector layer

Tags: qgis, import, gml

I am new (today) to QGIS and I have hit a problem almost immediately. Basically, I am trying to read in a number of GML files, each with unique names. However when I import them into QGIS they get renamed to "PREDEFINED". The problem with this is that I want to use the python console to loop some functions, however, all the layers are named the same, so I can't do it.

I have a lot of GML files (345) and hence, to manually rename them is not an option.

I don't know what technical information you might need, I am using windows 8 and QGIS Desktop.

Comment: Imported as vector layer.

Comment: The layer name is the one that is used inside the GML, not derived from the file name. You can test it with ogrinfo. Perhaps you could make a script and give unique names for the layers with Python.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the information that I needed. If you put this in the answer I will give you a thumbs up or whatever the stack-exchange equivalent is.